# IE8 ignores td width, works on IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, html-table, width

There is a table looking like this:

```
<table width="100%">
<tr id="header">
 <td colspan="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr id="center">
 <td id="left" style="width: 201px"></td>
 <td id="mainpage" style="width: 100%"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

In every browser (including IE7) apart from IE8 the "left" td is fine. In IE8 it exceeds the width according to the mainpage's content.

I'd post some screenshots but it's my first post here.

Any ideas whatsoever?

Comment: how you want to make total width of table 201px + 100% ??

Comment: I don't. But this layout fixes the IE7 issue. And it doesn't affect IE8.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

That `width: 100%` on the second column doesn't look right - if you're trying to make the second column expand to the rest of the available space, you shouldn't need that at all, so you can remove it.
Also, add this to your table:

```
table-layout: fixed;
```

to make sure that the widths are obeyed.

complete code:

```
<table style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed;">
<colgroup>
    <col style="width: 201px">
</colgroup>
<tr id="header">
    <td colspan="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr id="center">
    <td id="left"></td>
    <td id="mainpage"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thought about this and gave it a try, but once I set the table-layout to fixed the two columns get the same width (50%) and it ignores the fixed values.

The 100% of the second column is there as a fix for IE7.

Comment: Please try the edited solution with added cols - not a terribly cool solution but it works.

Comment: Indeed it does! Seems better than my solution, I'll go with that.

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much... this fixed my problem... That IE (sigh)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it should be `100%`

```
<table width="100%">
```

The table will be as large as its parent element. May be you should set a fixed width for the table:

```
<table width="600">
```

Comment: The table resides in a div that fits the whole screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a width to your table and to your first  you don't need to define it for your second .

I guess the second  gets 100% from container which is the table.

Answer (score 0):

Well, problem somewhat fixed by adding an empty table with a fixed width inside the mainpage .

That way I'm actually setting a min-width to the  regardless IE's ignoring attitude. Thanks for all the answers.