# Rupees Symbol Image Is not Visible in IE 8,9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, twig

What i Need:

- i need Indian rupees symbol visible in ie 8.
- i have used rupees image because rupees symbol not visible in ie 8.
- its working fine in mozilla ,google chrome.

snapshot of ie 8

[image]

code im using

```
     {% if curr == 'INR' %}
    <td width="12%" class="aligncenter " style="border-top:0px"><img src="/img/rupees_symbol.png" />{{ value.amount }} </td>
    {% else %}
    <td width="12%" class="aligncenter " style="border-top:0px">{{curr}} {{ value.amount }} </td>
     {%endif%}
```

- please tell me where i have done wrong though its working fine forghrome  and firefox.
- any suggestion are most welcome.
- solution i have tried with ie 8

  ```
      <span style="font-family: DejaVu Sans;">&#x20b9;</span>
  ```
- but it is not working ie 9.

  ```
          <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
  ```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306861/ie8-ignores-td-width-works-on-ie7 ?

Comment: i have updated ie 8 ,9 snapshot

Comment: You should Check this:- 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741931/indian-rupee-symbol

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Empty rectanglar box is displayed instead of the rupee symbol in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37643675/empty-rectanglar-box-is-displayed-instead-of-the-rupee-symbol-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer 8 does not support the .PNG file format very well. First, try replacing your image with some standard text to make sure that your code is working and that the problem is in fact the image.

If you get text where the image was then we can be sure that the issue is the image itself.  Try replacing the image with a .GIF or .JPG and see if that resolves the issue.

If that does not fix the problem then perhaps your relative link to /img/myimage is not correct, make sure that the location exists and is accessible.

There may also be a problem with using table cells and the % width, try using a fixed width instead of a percentage.

If you must absolutely use PNG and support IE8, here is a link that talks about a CSS hack to work with it.

http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/ie-transparency-problems/

Comment: rs rupees resmbel in ie 8,9  a rectangular box symbol

Answer (score 0):

If you use any ₹ `&#x20B9;` it will not work in IE so i think best option is to use svg image. it will work fine with ie8+

You can try this:-

> http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130318203705/green/images/e/ee/Indian_Rupee_symbol.svg

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wxtu90v2/)**

Comment: I HAVE TRIED WITH <span style="font-family: DejaVu Sans;">&#x20b9;</span> it work fine with ie 8 but not working with ie 9

Comment: If you try `font-family` then try Font-Awesome. http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/

Comment: Yes it will in ie8 also, but before that you have to add `<script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>` this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64921/discussion-between-maddy-and-user3785613).